# Hide "Separator" in XML View - OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, string, odoo, separator

I need to hide a "Separator" and all it's child items (trees, fields, buttons, etc), i'm stuck and don't know how to achieve this

```
<separator string="Quotations" />
                    <field name="purchase_ids" readonly="1">
                        <tree string="Purchase Order">
                            <field name="name" string="Reference"/>
                            <field name="date_order" string="Order Date"/>
                            <field name="partner_id"/>
                            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
                            <field name="location_id" groups="stock.group_locations"/>
                            <field name="minimum_planned_date"/>
                            <field name="origin"/>
                            <field name="state"/>
                            <button name="purchase_cancel" states="draft,confirmed,wait_auth" string="Cancel Purchase Order" icon="gtk-cancel"/>
                            <button name="purchase_confirm" states="draft" string="Confirm Purchase Order" icon="gtk-apply"/>
                            <button name="purchase_approve" states="confirmed" string="Approved by Supplier" icon="gtk-ok"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
```

If anybody could help, would be very appreciated, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to hide fields for particular roles/groups, you can use groups attribute like this:

```
<field name="name" groups="GROUP_XML_ID"/>
```

It means that if your current user has no this group, He won't be able to see those fields.

If you need to hide fields for particular conditions, you can use attrs attribute like this:

```
<separator string="Description" colspan="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_config', '=', False)]}" />
```

Otherwise, invisible="1" would be nice to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`position="replace"` attribute will remove whatever you want to remove from xml.

```
<separator string="Quotations" position="replace"/>
<field name="purchase_ids" position="replace"/>
```

Comment: In my own answer is the code, i don't get it but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

Its better to add attribute 'invisible'=True than making the field invisible.  So first find the correct view, then replace the seperator, then add the attribute invisible to the field purchase_ids

```
<separator string="Quotations" position="replace"/>
<field name="purchase_ids" position="attributes">
<attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute>
</field>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, i'm going to try it, i just solved it by adding (invisible="True") to the separator and field, worked well, don't know if it's the safest way to do it though, i'll try your solution anyways, i'm still learning openerp, thank you very much!

Comment: dont use replace for fields as there is a change of bugs

Answer (score 0):

```
<separator string="Quotations" position="replace"/>
                    <field name="purchase_ids" position="replace">
                        <tree string="Purchase Order" position="replace">
                            <field name="name" string="Reference"/>
                            <field name="date_order" string="Order Date"/>
                            <field name="partner_id"/>
                            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
                            <field name="location_id" groups="stock.group_locations"/>
                            <field name="minimum_planned_date"/>
                            <field name="origin"/>
                            <field name="state"/>
                            <button name="purchase_cancel" states="draft,confirmed,wait_auth" string="Cancel Purchase Order" icon="gtk-cancel"/>
                            <button name="purchase_confirm" states="draft" string="Confirm Purchase Order" icon="gtk-apply"/>
                            <button name="purchase_approve" states="confirmed" string="Approved by Supplier" icon="gtk-ok"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
```

Comment: Hi, instead of changing the original source try to inherit the respective view and apply the changes there. You can achieve this by creating a new module.